# Knex.js: How to create table, insert data, get select query results, then return

Tags: javascript, promise, knex.js

The following snippet creates the database file, creates the table, inserts the data, queries and outputs it, but then it just hangs.

I need it to return the query result, output to console, then end the process.

What am I missing?

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    // debug: true,
    connection: {
    filename: "example.db"
    },
    useNullAsDefault: true
});

const data = [
    {
        col1: "one",
        col2: "two",
        col3: "three"
    },
    {
        col1: "a",
        col2: "b",
        col3: "c"
    },
    {
        col1: "1",
        col2: "2",
        col3: "3"
    }        
];

knex.schema.createTable('myTable', table => {
    table.increments();
    table.string("col1");
    table.string("col2");
    table.string("col3");
})
.then(function(){
    return knex('myTable').insert(data);
})
.then(function(){
    return knex('myTable').select();
})
.then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that adding a knex.destroy() call helps; it does resolve the promise, but I"m not sure if it is the correct approach.

```
knex.schema.createTable('myTable', table => {
    table.increments();
    table.string("col1");
    table.string("col2");
    table.string("col3");
})
.then(function(){
    return knex('myTable').insert(data);
})
.then(function(){
    return knex('myTable').select();
})
.finally(function(queryResult){
    knex.destroy();
    return queryResult;
})
.catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Yes, destroying the database connection is useful if you're done with it, but if you're just running a query and returning a result, it's overkill. I don't see you're ever using the data in a meaningful way here following the `select`, so it makes sense to destroy in this context since it appears the application is ready to exit, but probably doesn't make sense in a larger application where you're actually doing something with the data and running repeated queries over time, e.g. a web app.